# Want to create dynamic array with json object

Tags: angular

i have an array and i want to iterate that and push that array to a newly created json object.

```
this is my json with key value pair
'fileContent': {
           'content': [{
             'effectiveDate': '4/23/2019',
             'supplierId': 'ABD',
             'sailCode': 'CM0123',
             'Departure Date': '4/23/2019',
             'reportId': 7960
           },
           {
             'effectiveDate': '4/23/2019',
             'supplierId': 'ABD',
             'sailCode': 'CM0123',
             'Departure Date': '4/23/2019',
             'reportId': 7960
           }
         ],'fileContent': {
           'content': [{
             'effectiveDate': '4/23/2019',
             'supplierId': 'ABD',
             'sailCode': 'CM0123',
             'Departure Date': '4/23/2019',
             'reportId': 7960
           },
           {
             'effectiveDate': '4/23/2019',
             'supplierId': 'ABD',
             'sailCode': 'CM0123',
             'Departure Date': '4/23/2019',
             'reportId': 7960
           }
         ],
Requirement is i have to show the key as header and value as their property in each row. i am using ag-grid.

(1): i am able to get the content and key also 

    this.assiengedValue = fileContent.content;



    const types = Object.keys(this.assiengedValue[0]);

    (2): i want to iterate and put that into dynamic array like this.
    uiHeader[{'headerName':'effectiveDate','field': 'effectiveDate',
             {'headerName':'SupplierId','filed':'supplierId'},
             {'headerName':'SailCode','field':'sailCode'}

    ]
```

Expected: those filed should come inside an array with headerName and field so i can set that in columnDefs.

Comment: Can you please post the exact array you want to achieve?

Comment: i have solved this issue.